# Soap Error Message "Soap message is invalid!"

Tags: android, ksoap2

My code as follows

```
portpackage com.demo;

import android.util.Log;

import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;

import java.io.IOException;

import okhttp3.Call;
import okhttp3.Callback;
import okhttp3.MediaType;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.RequestBody;

/**
 * Created by shaileshp on 15-Mar-18.
 */

public class HttpUtils {

    private static final MediaType SOAP_MEDIA_TYPE = MediaType.parse("text/xml");
    private static final String soap_action = "urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/codeunit/HelloWorld:PrintHello";
    private static final String namespace = "urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/codeunit/HelloWorld";
    private static final String method_name = "PrintHello";

    public static void doGetRequest() throws IOException {
        SoapObject soapObject = new SoapObject(namespace, method_name);
        soapObject.addProperty("Username", "ravia");
        soapObject.addProperty("Password", "Ravi@123");
        soapObject.addProperty("Domain", "techcronus");
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(soapObject);
        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder().authenticator(new NTLMAuthenticator("ravia", "Ravi@123", "techcronus", "")).build();
        RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(SOAP_MEDIA_TYPE, String.valueOf(envelope.getResponse()));
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("http://192.168.1.199:1013/MISReports/WS/Test/Codeunit/HelloWorld")
                .post(body)
                .addHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8")
                .addHeader("soapaction", soap_action)
                .build();
//        okhttp3.Response response = okHttpClient.newCall(request).execute();

        okHttpClient.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                Log.e(HttpUtils.class.getSimpleName(), "onFailure: " + e.getMessage());
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, okhttp3.Response response) throws IOException {
                Log.e(HttpUtils.class.getSimpleName(), "onResponse: " + response.body().string());
            }
        });

//        return response.body().string();
    }

}
```

When I run the application at that time I got the response like

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body>
        <s:Fault>
            <faultcode xmlns:a="urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/error">a:Microsoft.Dynamics.Nav.Service.WebMetadata.ServiceBrokerException
            </faultcode>
            <faultstring xml:lang="en-US">Soap message is invalid!
            </faultstring>
            <detail>
                <string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">Soap message is invalid!
                </string>
            </detail>
        </s:Fault>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

I'm trying to get response from okhttp.
Please help me out this to find where the actual problem is and at where I have to make changes to run successfully soap action and get the response from it.

Please help me anybody who has proper solution to my question.